# Python-requests: Can't scrape all the html code from a page

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the content of the
[Financial Times Search](http://search.ft.com/search?q=SABMiller%20PLC&t=all&rpp=100&fa=people%2Corganisations%2Cregions%2Csections%2Ctopics%2Ccategory%2Cbrand&s=-lastPublishDateTime&f=lastPublishDateTime%5B2000-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%2C2016-01-01T23%3A59%3A59%5D&curations=ARTICLES%2CBLOGS%2CVIDEOS%2CPODCASTS&highlight=true&p=1) page.

Using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), I can easily **scrape** the articles' titles and hyperlinks.

I would like to get the next page's hyperlink, but I can not find it in the Requests response, unlike the articles' titles or hyperlinks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://search.ft.com/search?q=SABMiller+PLC&t=all&rpp=100&fa=people%2Corganisations%2Cregions%2Csections%2Ctopics%2Ccategory%2Cbrand&s=-lastPublishDateTime&f=lastPublishDateTime[2000-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%2C2016-01-01T23%3A59%3A59]&curations=ARTICLES%2CBLOGS%2CVIDEOS%2CPODCASTS&highlight=true&p=1et'

response = requests.get(url, auth=(my login informations))
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

def get_titles_and_links():
    titles = soup.find_all('a')
    for ref in titles:
        if ref.get('title') and ref.get('onclick'):
            print ref.get('href')
            print ref.get('title')
```

The get_titles_and_links() function gives me the titles and links of all the articles.

However, with a similar function for the next page, I have no results:

```
def get_next_page():
    next_page = soup.find_all("li", class_="page next")
    return next_page
```

Or:

```
def get_next_page():
    next_page = soup.find_all('li')
    for ref in next_page:
        if ref.get('page next'):
            print ref.get('page next')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see the required links in the page source, but are not able to get them via `requests` or `urllib`. It can mean two things.

1. There is something wrong with your logic. *Let's assume it's not that.*
2. Then the thing remains is: **Ajax**, those parts of the page you are looking for are loaded by javascript **after** the `document.onload` method fired. So you cannot get something that's not there in the first place.

My solutions(more like suggestions) are

1. Reverse engineer the network requests. **Difficult, but universally applicable**. I personally do that. You might want to use `re` module.
2. Find something that *renders* javascript. That's just to say that, *simulate web browsing*. You might wanna check out the **webdriver** component of `selenium`, `Qt` etc. **This is easier, but kinda memory hungry and consumes a lot more network resource compared to 1**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped me to understand my problem. I used the [https://github.com/niklasb/dryscrape] module to scrape the webpage.

Comment: If it worked, that's great. But reverse engineering the network requests makes the concepts spectacularly clear. But it takes time.

Comment: Well, to be frank, with the quick Internet searches I did after your answer, I did not find any clear (to me) explanations about reverse engineering the network requests. And, I have to say, love a quick and easy solution.

Comment: They probably call it something else. What I meant was, open Firebug or Chrome developer tool and analyse the network requests and responses. Dealing with ajax is much easier because, the response content JSON most of the time. Much friendlier than html.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation, I will look into that.